# Detecting the end of a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, listiterator

I'm making a linked list of entry's in a Phone book. However I'm struggling to work out a complete delete method. I'm trying to detect the entry I'm trying to delete is not in the list, and give an 'Entry not found' message. I'm using the list interface for linked list. Here is the delete method so far. Now I've tried to cover the "last node" situation in the last if statement. But it doesn't work. If i was not using the list interface I guess I could use the getLast() method and compare it to the entry I'm currently on, but i'd prefer to do it this way and figure out another way to solve it. Any ideas ?
--edit the reason its not working is if I delete the last entry on the list, it print out the entry not found message even if the entry was there as the last node and was successfully deleted

```
 public void deleteEntry(String number) {
    ListIterator<Entry> i = phoneBook.listIterator();

    while(i.hasNext()){
        Entry e = i.next();
        if(e.getNumber().equals(number)){
            i.remove();
            break;
        }
    }
    if(phoneBook.size() != 0 && (!(i.hasNext()))){
        System.out.println("Entry not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you conider using basic `myList.remove(Object o)` method ? Or  is this a homework to give own implmentation of linkedList ?

Comment: As I'm deleting an Entry, each entry contains strings, for someones name and a telephone number. So I have to check each object to see if its the correct entry. I'm just wondering how to detect whether I'm at the end of the list

Comment: Why `phoneBook.size() != 0`? If the list is empty, then the entry is not found either... I don't understand why you exclude that case for your message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do it this way:

```
public void deleteEntry(String number) {
    int size = phoneBook.size();
    for (ListIterator<Entry> i = phoneBook.listIterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        Entry e = i.next();
        if (e.getNumber().equals(number)) {
            i.remove();
            break;
        }
    }
    if (phoneBook.size() == size) {
        System.out.println("Entry not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats great, although I think its if(phoneBook.size() == size){print out} - thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Replace the `break;` statement by `return;`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void deleteEntry(String number) {
    ListIterator<Entry> i = phoneBook.listIterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        Entry e = i.next();
        if(e.getNumber().equals(number)){
            i.remove();
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Entry not found");
}
```

But better change the return type to `boolean` and return `true` as soon as the number found, `false` otherwise at the end

Answer (score 0):

```
public void deleteEntry(String number) {
    ListIterator<Entry> i = phoneBook.listIterator();
    boolean found = false;
    while(i.hasNext()){


        Entry e = i.next();
        if(e.getNumber().equals(number)){
            if(!found)
        found = true;

            i.remove();
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!found){
        System.out.println("Entry not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: `found` will always be true if there is at least one element in the list, it does not depend on whether the entry is found or not.

Comment: also, you don't need `if (!found)`, because you exit the loop as soon as this boolean turns true anyway ;-) Even if we were not sure that found is false, assigning true to a true boolean is not wrong anyway ^^

Comment: I'm talking about the if in the loop, not the last one